# Question on new bike assembly

Tags: new-bicycle-assembly

If I order a Fat Bike online it will come in a box.
Is the assembly hard to do for someone fairly good with their hands?

Comment: Your other option is to get it delivered to a Local Bike Shop and have them do the assembly.  It will cost you several hours of their workshop time/rate.

Answer (score 3):

This depends how much it was assembled before going into the box. I've had one bike that just needed the stem bolts to be loosened and the stem rotated, plus the pedals fitted (using tools provided). The one I bought recently needed a little more work but still only using tools you'd carry on the road plus a pedal spanner. That was a used bike, and had been dismantled just enough to go back in the box.

The seller should be able to tell you exactly what is required. It's well worth asking them.

Important things to be aware of:

- Some bolts need to be done up to a specific torque.  On many bikes this can be quite roughly approximated but on carbon fibre and light alloy you shoudl really get a small adjustable torque wrench (sometimes sold as a torque screwdriver).  The parts should normally be marked when the torque matters.
- The left pedal has a left-hand thread.  Double check that you've got the pedals the right way round, then grease the threads and do them up with your fingers for severalturns before finally tightening with a pedal spanner (a thin 15mm open-ended spanner)

Comment: Agreed.   A few things to keep in mind during assembly:  Apply some bearing grease or anti-seize compound to the pedal axle threads before installing the pedals. One pedal is reverse thread.  Observe torque limits on stem steerer clamp screws, handlebar clamp screws, and seatpost clam screws, especially if carbon parts are part of the build.  I would suggest 5 N-m if you do not have other information on the limits.

Comment: Very good info. Especially the pedal with reverse threads. I will have to see about scaring up a torque wrench. The bike is probably coming from China.

Comment: I need to edit in @TimD's points, and maybe a few other tips. There are good guides to building bikes online. A torque wrench is useful on most bikes, essential on carbon and very light alloy. Adjustable torque screwdrivers aren't expensive on ebay and cover the right range, unlike many wrenches

Answer (score 2):

The level of expertise required will vary by the brand and the complexity of the bike. You will need a decent set of Allen wrenches and common hand tools such as wrenches and screwdrivers. I've assembled numerous bike for friends from a variety of sources. The easiest involved installing the front wheel, inserting the seat post, mounting the pedals and handlebars. Another required mounting the rotors to the wheels, the calipers to the frame, both wheels, bars and saddle. Then it also required some shifter and derailleur adjustment. I would suggest reading some of the Park Tool tutorials. Pay particular attention to derailleur and brake adjustments. While it is not rocket science it can be frustrating the first time you do it. If the bike comes out of the box really out adjustment and your attempt to correct it is unsuccessful then bring it to your Local Bike Shop and pay for the adjustments.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested I spoke with Moose Bikes and you don't have to do much more than put on the pedals. This question has been answered.

Comment: Not really - you've got an answer about one specific brand of bike, not a generic answer across all fatbikes.   To save shipping costs by having a smaller box, often the wheels are shipped beside the frame, in the box, and the handlebars may be rotated or dismounted completely.  So it will vary by manufacturer/supplier